# Need guidance for setup @ & @home BTRFS subvolume in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: grub2, filesystem, btrfs, 23.04

I want to get full guidance how to create @ and @home BTRFS subvolume in Ubuntu 23.04. I always get failed and finally failed to booting to my system.

Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry my English